# SQL Server - XML to SQL table mapping

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I am trying to insert XML into SQL table but it is either adding first row or only one column.

Here is my XML

```xml
<SessionDataIds>
    <SelectedIds>
       <SelectedId>388439424</SelectedId>
       <SelectedId>388436066</SelectedId>
       <SelectedId>388435999</SelectedId>
       <SelectedId>388439450</SelectedId>
       <SelectedId>388439463</SelectedId>
       <SelectedId>388433795</SelectedId>
    </SelectedIds>
    <VendorId>
        <VendorIds>609004</VendorIds>
        <VendorIds>609004</VendorIds>
        <VendorIds>609004</VendorIds>
        <VendorIds>609004</VendorIds>
        <VendorIds>609004</VendorIds>
        <VendorIds>609003</VendorIds>
    </VendorId>
</SessionDataIds>
```

Please help

Below are the solutions I tried

solution #1

```sql
INSERT INTO #sessionData_CTE (sessionDataId,vendorId)
SELECT DISTINCT
    T.C.value('(SelectedIds/SelectedId/text())[1]', 'int')AS sessionDataId,
    T.C.value('(VendorId/VendorIds/text())[2]', 'int')AS vendorId
from @sessionDataIdXmlInner.nodes('//SessionDataIds') as T(C);
```

Comment: and which databse system are you using?

Comment: How would the database know that the first `/SessionDataIds/SelectedIds/SelectedId` corresponds to the second `/SessionDataIds/VendorId/VendorIds/` and must be put on the same row with it? If there is a join rule, select your two tables of nodes, `.nodes(N'/SessionDataIds/SelectedIds/SelectedId/')` and `.nodes(N'/SessionDataIds/VendorId/VendorIds/')`, and join them on that rule.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A a minimal reproducible example is not provided. So, I am shooting from the hip.

The **sessionDataId** and the **vendorId** are tied based on a sequential order in the XML.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @xml XML =
N'<SessionDataIds>
    <SelectedIds>
       <SelectedId>388439424</SelectedId>
       <SelectedId>388436066</SelectedId>
       <SelectedId>388435999</SelectedId>
       <SelectedId>388439450</SelectedId>
       <SelectedId>388439463</SelectedId>
       <SelectedId>388433795</SelectedId>
    </SelectedIds>
    <VendorId>
        <VendorIds>609004</VendorIds>
        <VendorIds>609004</VendorIds>
        <VendorIds>609004</VendorIds>
        <VendorIds>609004</VendorIds>
        <VendorIds>609004</VendorIds>
        <VendorIds>609003</VendorIds>
    </VendorId>
</SessionDataIds>';

;WITH rs1 AS
(
    SELECT id = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@SPID)
        , c.value('(text())[1]', 'int')AS sessionDataId
    from @xml.nodes('/SessionDataIds/SelectedIds/SelectedId') AS t(c)
), rs2 AS
(
    SELECT id = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@SPID)
        , c.value('(text())[1]', 'int')AS vendorId
    from @xml.nodes('/SessionDataIds/VendorId/VendorIds') AS t(c)
)
SELECT rs1.* , rs2.vendorId
FROM rs1 INNER JOIN rs2 ON rs2.id = rs1.id;
```

**Output**

| id | sessionDataId | vendorId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 388439424 | 609004 |
| 2 | 388436066 | 609004 |
| 3 | 388435999 | 609004 |
| 4 | 388439450 | 609004 |
| 5 | 388439463 | 609004 |
| 6 | 388433795 | 609003 |